# How do I merge smoothing shaders seemlessly without joining objects?

Tags: shaders, normals

I'm having an issue with creating a game asset for the Creation Engine.

I am trying to have two objects, a head and body, match seamlessly together without joining them. They don't and it's because the normal vectors have a mind of their own, unless I join the objects and weld them together (alt+m).

The smoothing shaders look like a complete mismatch between the two objects. I've tried editing them both, by having two selected and entering edit mode, and then trying to calculate the normals based upon selection, but nothing I've tried seems to be working. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Adding some images to your question might go a long way in helping you get any answers

Comment: Make an intact (welded) copy of the parts, and [use a Data Transfer modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159020/35559) to transfer the normals from the intact copy to the separated parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy normals from one object to the other, using a data transfer modifier.  Use a vertex group to limit the data transfer so that it only affects relevant vertices:

[image]

Some terms and conditions apply: Custom normals require autosmooth (properties/object data/normals) to be enabled.  Custom normals are still vertex data, so topology still matters. The better that the copying verts match the copied verts (position + topo), the better the result will be. Normals are not position, and you'd be wise to precede this with a shrinkwrap if there's any positional disagreement, for shadows etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the smoothing shader **>** merge those 2 objects using *CTLR+J* **>** smooth that one *(merged)* object **>** apply the modifier **>** once you're done and you're not going to edit the model anymore, in edit mode select one edge that between your head and body and press *P*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Teglik! I thought I'd try that as well, like in 3ds Max, this is often fixable by clearing the smoothing groups and auto smoothing the mesh, or using the same smoothing groups. Although, in Blender 2.8 (at least), every time I separate the object, it creates the issue again, no matter where I separate it at. I was hoping there was some type of way to reference the object to create seamless normal vectors.

Comment: Please upload your file here [https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/] and post a comment with the link it will generate.

Comment: I got a 404 with that site, so here's a mediafire link: (if it'll let me post)
https://www.mediafire.com/file/z83rn4dawdrmu9p/Arrg%21_First_world_normals_problems%21.7z/file

Comment: Alright, so, to be honest, I have no idea how to fix it, but I'll try to think about a way how to do that.

Comment: So, I sorta fixed it. It's a dirty fix, but if anyone else knows something better, like a script to blend normals (I think Maya has one, but alas I have no Maya), then that'd be awesome. What I did was extrude the edge neck of the body on Z-axis, then create a loop cut on the head to match the new loop on the body by snappings, then delete the body extruded loop. https://www.mediafire.com/file/b71d94c26m0s0gq/Arrg%21_First_world_normals_problems%21_Fixished.7z/file
Still looking for a better way, because this isn't perfect. Thanks for the input Teglik.